# I created a user in mySQL db (insert) but cannot login to Laravel application with that user

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-authentication

I recently created a couple of users in my database which is linked to a laravel application. When I register through the application, I can login just fine with that user but all the other users created in mySQL using insert are unable to login.

My error: These credentials do not match our records.

I used "php artisan make:auth" to generate login and register pages.

Is there some other elements that Laravel uses to authenticate the users apart from the email address and password?

Comment: Did you hash the password for that user or stored it plaintext?

Comment: All passwords are hashed. I just need laravel to pick them up as users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Password are hashed from within the `Authentication service` of `Laravel`, in order to create a user, you should do so via `php artisan tinker` or via the provided Registration interface of the page.

See: [Laravel Manual Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#authenticating-users)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there no way I can link the users in the db without having to register them through Laravel?

Comment: If you want for them to use the integrated logic functionality of Laravel, you will need to `hash` the password as previously mentioned. But you can create your own Authentication service and from there one define the logic on how the users can Authenticate themselfs (for example not hashing the password). I would not recommend not hashing the password, as this is a security issue, where if someone get access to your database, it can see all the users password, which is why we Hash them, though if it is for a personal project not accessible from the network - it would be fine. :)